# BASH script variables have no values

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I am writing a simple script to clean up log folders.  This is the most basic thing I can think of, and yet it does not work because the variables don't seem to be set.  Here is the shell script beginning, where it fails:

```
#!/bin/bash
X3DBASE=/data/DassaultSystemes/R2020x
echo X3DBASE=$X3DBASE
read
```

And, here is the output:

```
$ ./cleanlogs.sh
X3DBASE=
^C
$
```

What am I doing wrong?  I also tried removing the first line, in case a shell specification were somehow messing things up.

Comment: Works for me. Are you running the correct script?

Comment: check for spaces around the = sign, ensure no typos in variable names, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I did check for spaces, no spaces.  If I modify the echo command and re-run, the output changes, so I am definitely running the same script (good 'newb' question tho!).

Comment: Try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so it'll print an execution trace as it runs and you can get a better idea what bash thinks is happening.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a perfect case of misreading the screen.  The variable names are so close but 1 character different.  Put this one down to error between seat and keyboard.

Comment: `bash -u` is fairly useful for tracking down unset variable which depending on the script, may be symptomatic of a typo.

Comment: Thanks G!  That is really great to know.